# ransack searching each word in a text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I will searching with ransack in my Rails application for users by firstname and lastname. In one text_field for firstname and one text_field for lastname the application user should have the possibility to search for several parts of the name.

E.g. the user will enter "Thomas Jeffrey" and this should results in:

```
SELECT FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE "%Thomas%" AND firstname LIKE "%Jeffrey%";
```

If I use firstname_cont the result looks like:

```
SELECT FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE "%Thomas Jeffrey%";
```

When I was trying firstname_cont_all out, I got something different.

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 2):

```
User.search(firstname_cont_all: params[:my_field].split)
```

I do not know, however, how to properly introduce that splitting to array when using ransack's `condition_field` form builder utility.